# leaflet marker add/remove via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, leaflet

I want to remove old marker Instead of new marker via ajax request. the first time it works but the second time it's not working. I use change event for this.

**My Problem**

```
<code>

    if(map.hasLayer(markers)){
       map.removeLayer(markers);
    }

</code>
```

1. map.hasLayer(markers) first time retrun true and successfully remove marker
2. second time map.hasLayer(markers) return false but marker is still now show in my map
3. i also try with **updatemarker.clearLayers();** it work first time but second time not working

Note: actually my problem is first marker/layer removed from the map. I use change event. it works first change but second change not working

**Here is my full code**

```
<code>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // calculate distance
            function calcDistance(fromLat, fromLng, toLat, toLng) {
                return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
                new google.maps.LatLng(fromLat, fromLng), new google.maps.LatLng(toLat, toLng));
            }
            // get user current location
            var currentLocation = null;
            $('#get_location').on('click', function(){
                var currentAction = $(this);
                if ("geolocation" in navigator){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ 
                        var currentLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
                        var currentLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
                        currentLocation = currentLatitude +','+currentLongitude;
                        $(currentAction).parent().addClass('active');
                    });
                }
            });
            $('.range-slider__range').on('change', function(){
                var updatemarker = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
                var radius = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) * 1000;
                var data = {
                    'action'            : 'my_action',
                    'radius'            : $(this).val(),
                    'currentLocation'   : currentLocation
                };
                // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
                jQuery.post('<?php print admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function(response, status) {
                    if(status == 'success'){
                        var existingResponseInRadius = [];
                        var existingResponseHTML = '';
                        var currentLocationArray = currentLocation.split(',');

                        $.each(response,function(index, value){
                            var distance = calcDistance(currentLocationArray[0], currentLocationArray[1], response[index].lat, response[index].lng);

                            if (distance < radius){ 
                                existingResponseInRadius.push(value);
                                existingResponseHTML += value.content;
                            }      
                        });
                        $('#cplgr-listing-search-result').html(existingResponseHTML);
                        // update post counter
                        $('#post_count').text($('.listing-single').length);

                        var addressPoints = document.getElementsByClassName('listing-single');

                        console.log(map.hasLayer(markers));

                        if(map.hasLayer(markers)){
                             map.removeLayer(markers);
                        }

                        if (addressPoints.length > 0 ){
                            for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {

                                var markerContent = document.getElementsByClassName('listing-single');
                                // 
                                var helloLondonHtmlIcon = new L.HtmlIcon({
                                    html: "<div class='marker mcn" + jQuery(addressPoints[i]).data("postid") + "' data-markerid=" + jQuery(addressPoints[i]).data("postid") + "><img src='" + jQuery(addressPoints[i]).data('mapicon') + "' alt='icon' /></div>",
                                    markerid: "" + jQuery(addressPoints[i]).data("postid") + "",
                                });
                                // 
                                updatemarker.on('clusterclick', function () {
                                    var helloLondonHtmlIcon = new L.HtmlIcon({
                                        html: "<div class=marker mcn" + jQuery(addressPoints[i]).data("postid") + " data-markerid=" + jQuery(addressPoints[i]).data("postid") + "></div>",
                                        markerid: "" + jQuery(addressPoints[i]).data("postid") + "",
                                    });
                                });

                                // update map position
                                map.panTo(new L.LatLng(jQuery(addressPoints[0]).data("lat"), jQuery(addressPoints[0]).data("lng")));

                                var popupInfo = markerContent[i];
                                var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(jQuery(addressPoints[i]).data("lat"), jQuery(addressPoints[i]).data("lng")), { icon: helloLondonHtmlIcon });
                                marker.bindPopup(popupInfo.cloneNode(true), { minWidth: 300, offset: new L.Point(0, -170) });
                                updatemarker.addLayer(marker);
                            }
                            map.addLayer(updatemarker);
                        } else {
                            updatemarker.clearLayers();
                            map.panTo(new L.LatLng('-52.945287', '12.014960'));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

</code>
```

Answer (score -1):

change your  on click function for example "$('#get_location').on('click', function(){"
to  "$(document.body).on('click','#get_location', function(){" ...
It's should  work ..

Comment: no get_location is work. my problem is $('.range-slider__range').on('change', function(){} event